# Java List can not retrieve over 90.000 elements

Tags: java, hibernate

I am dealing with an issue when I attempt to retrieve a large amount of records from a database. It seems that when the amount of records exceed 90.000, the elements can not be retrieved.

When that happens I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value.
```

The code that I am using is the following one:

```
Session objSession;
List<GroupEntity> colResults;
objSession = this.objSessionFactory.openSession();
try
{
    objQuery = objSession.createQuery("FROM GroupEntity WHERE (strDomain = :Domain)")
        .setParameter("Domain",  strDomain)
        .list();
}
catch (Exception objException)
{
    throw new GroupException("Could not retrieve the list of WebFiltering groups to scan");
}
objSession.close();
return colResults;
```

I attempt to page the results retrieved by sets of 1.000, using this method when I insert up to 89.999 records the list is fine. however when I exceed 90.000 I get the same exception.

Any idea about how to face this issue?

Comment: Could you attach full stack trace? It could be not ArrayList problem but problem of ObjectSessionFactory. What library do you use to perform SQL queries?

Comment: This exception is thrown because your objects were Garbage Collected. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectCollectedException.html

Answer (score 2):

In case you process such a big amount of data I'd recommend that you use batch processing with `ScrollableResults`: https://grokonez.com/hibernate/resolve-hibernate-outofmemoryerror-problem-hibernate-batch-processing

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    ScrollableResults dataCursor = session.createQuery("FROM Data").scroll();

    int count = 1;
    while (dataCursor.next()) {
        Data data = (Data) dataCursor.get(0);
        String newText = Utilities.generatedRandomString();
        data.setText(newText);
        session.update(data);

        if (count % 50 == 0) {
            System.out.println("============================log: count = " + count);
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
        count++;
    }

    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (null != tx) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

In this case session will not keep all 90000 records in memory.

Answer (score 2):

"com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException" happens when the object you referring to is garbage collected.

there is no such limit of size on java arrayList.